# XAML DataTemplate only ever creates one instance

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, tabcontrol

The following only ever creates one instance of `MyTabView`. I've confirmed this by putting a breakpoint in the constructor in MyTabView.xaml.cs. The view is displayed in a tab, and however many tabs I create, I only ever hit that constructor once.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyTabViewModel}" x:Shared="false">
    <vw:MyTabView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Tab control:

```
    <TabControl
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}"
        >
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl>
```

This causes all the tabs to reflect share any state that's not bound to a view model: If you move a `GridSplitter`, that's the same `GridSplitter` in all the other tabs, so it appears to the user that you moved all of them. It's absurd.

I don't understand. Is there any way to use `TabControl` with multiple items of the same type?

EDIT: Added `x:Shared="false"` to `DataTemplate`.

**UPDATE:**

So I've found a couple of fixes, but I don't like them very much. I'm going to take a look at writing a Converter that converts `ObservableCollection<Object>` to `ObservableCollection<TabItem>` -- kind of like a live-updated version of

```
coll.Select(vm => new TabItem() { Content = vm });
```

...but we'll see whether or not it likes getting `TabItem` instances from `ItemsSource`. My money says don't bet on it. But we'll see.

**UPDATE 2:** Took a while to get back to this. The gimmick with swapping in a collection of tab items works, though `SelectedItem` is problem. Turns out there's another solution (below) that doesn't create that issue, and also avoids the complexity and goofiness of creating a "middleman" collection that has to mirror changes in the source collection.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839633/datatemplate-xshared-false-has-no-impact-on-the-view ? Not sure if the TabControl effectively uses virtualization since only one thing can be shown at a time...

Comment: @Tim Oh boy. Virtualization. I think you may have nailed it.

Comment: @Tim Turns out that may not be the problem. I switched to a DevExpress grid and it (mis)behaves identically. We use it on our main application though and it works correctly.

Comment: ...it works correctly do to a weird ancient kludge where the tab items are created explicitly. Always wondered why.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `x:Shared="false"` attribute to your template.

Comment: No effect. Sorry, forgot to include that in the example.

Comment: Have you tried applying to the `<vw:MyTabView />` inside the template also?

Comment: It says 'The "Shared" attribute can only be used on an element that is contained in "ResourceDictionary".'

Answer (score -1):

I had some problems with `ElementName` bindings within the `DataTemplate` when using the accepted approach with `dataTemplate.LoadContent`.

Building on the Solution from @EdPlunkett, I tried to utilize an intermediate `ContentPresenter` per `TabItem` and it works well for my usage scenario.

- Multiple tabs with the same template and same datacontext Type but different actual data contained
- GridSplitter inside the DataTemplate
- ElementName Binding inside the DataTemplate
- I don't care whether the `TabControl` virtualization works for my amount of tabs (and I didn't check what happens to virtualization in my case)

Xaml:

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="TabItem_Loaded"/>
    </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
<TabControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplateKey">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

Code behind (I changed `DataTemplateKey` to a string based key just for my use case with a named template resource. The `DataTemplateKey` approach for selecting the template should work as well)

```
private void TabItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tabItem = (sender as TabItem);

    if (null != tabItem.DataContext)
    {
        var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)tabItem.FindResource("MyTemplateKey");

        var cp = new ContentPresenter();
        cp.ContentTemplate = dataTemplate;
        cp.Content = tabItem.DataContext;
        tabItem.Content = cp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had yet another version of this problem. I have a UserControl with 2 grid columns. When selecting a TreeView node from the left grid column, it sets a ContentPresenter/Content on the right. My problem was that the rendered DataTemplate/UserControl in the ContentPresenter has a ListView which is instantiated only once. The result is when choosing a new item from the left-side-TreeView, the right-side UserControl/ListView would not deselect items from before.

Hopefully the above makes sense. Long-story-short, I found that the easiest solution is to create a **DataTemplateSelector** that always returns null from **SelectTemplate**.

```cs
public class DynamicTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

XAML looks like this:


<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DynamicTemplateSelector x:Key="DynamicSelector" />

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
        <local:MyUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
    ...

<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem}"
    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DynamicSelector}"
    />
```